# Formatting multiple axes in D3 indivdiually

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axes

I'm following the [Scatterplot Matrix example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3213173#index.html), but I have axes that require different formatting. I have some time-oriented variables and some standard numeric variables. I want the axes to have different formats, because currently, the time-oriented labels show up with commas (e.g. 2,005 rather than 2005). I have tried appending

```
   .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
```

to

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
```

but this formats all of the axes as dates. Is there a way to format each axis differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down `xAxis` is called to render the axis:

```
.each(function(d, i) {
  x.domain(domainByTrait[d]);
  d3.select(this).call(xAxis);
});
```

That function is called once per trait `d`, so from there you can call

```
xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(...))
```

or

```
.tickFormat(d3.time.format(...))
```

before rendering the axis.